# php show max number of counter

Tags: php, counter

I have a counter in a foreach(){} carrossel  that is showing me the current slide. But how do I display the max number of the counter?
This way I could do something like **slide 1 of 3**.

```
 $count_slide = 0;

    foreach( $featured_posts as $post ) {
    $count_slide++;
   ?> <p> <?php echo $count_slide ?> - Show Max Value</p><?
    ...
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: How should we know? You did not show your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
<?php
$featured_posts = ['slide1', 'slide2', 'slide3', 'slide4', 'slide5', 'slide6', 'slide7'];

$counter = 0;
$maxCounter = count($featured_posts);
foreach ($featured_posts as $post ) {
    $counter = ($counter % $maxCounter) + 1;
    echo sprintf("slide %s of %s\n", $counter, $maxCounter);
}
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
slide 1 of 7
slide 2 of 7
slide 3 of 7
slide 4 of 7
slide 5 of 7
slide 6 of 7
slide 7 of 7
```

Comment: Oh there is a function for that. I should have mentioned I was working with wordpress. 
Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Even wordpress can't ruin php that far that you cannot use such functions ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I have it working already with this: "$maxCounter = count($featured_posts);"

Comment: you right. This is just too many hours in front of the screen. ...Feeling dumb....  Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Are the sldes for your carousel in an array?

If so, you can count($array) to get the total number of slides.

Failing that, you can increment a counter variable at the end of the foreach:

```
    $counterVar=0;
    foreach($this as $that) {
      // your code
    $counterVar++;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to averytime I come back to the firsts slides to show me the max value like:
Slide 1-3
Slide 2-3
Slide 3-3

And that way i can't do it.

Thanks :)